# Find files that were conflicting or locally edited during git merge commit

Tags: git, merge, pre-commit

Background: I'm working on a pre-commit tool.  As a developer it can be quite frustrating to pull another developer's branch and have the pre-commit hook complain loudly about files that I haven't even touched.

What I'd like to be able to do in my implementation is in a merge-commit case only run the hooks on files that were either *conflicting* or *manually edited by me* locally during the merge conflict.

What I've tried so far:

- `git diff --staged` - This is what the current solution does and isn't correct because it contains **all** of the files including the ones that merged cleanly.
- `git diff MERGE_HEAD` - This is pretty close, but if the branch I am merging in branched from master *after* I did, this contains all of the changes from master that I haven't yet merged.
- `.git/MERGE_MSG` contains the list of conflicting files.  This seems like a good starting point but does not contain locally edited files.
- **After committing**, `git show --name-only` gets me exactly what I want.  But that's too late (I'm implementing pre-commit after all :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution is `git diff -m`. I found the doc on this very confusing, so here's my summary. Given the command `git diff -m child parent1 parent2 ....` you'll see a multi-parent diff that shows how to get from each parent to the child. `parent1` represented in the first column of `[ +-]` and so on. The major roadblock here is that the child in your question has no referenceable name. `git write-tree` comes to the rescue here; it creates a name for the currently-staged files, and prints it out.

Note that write-tree will fail if there are any unmerged files, which is probably what you want, but you'll need to make sure your system does something intelligible in that case.

```bsh
$ CURRENTLY_ADDED=`git write-tree`
$ git diff -m $CURRENTLY_ADDED HEAD MERGE_HEAD
diff --cc README
index 2ef4a65,8e2e466..be3d46e
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@@ -1,10 -1,5 +1,10 @@@
 -deleted only in <theirs>
 +added only in <theirs>
- deleted only in <ours>
+ added only in <ours>
--deleted during merge
++added during merge
```

Comment: `git diff -m \`git write-tree\` HEAD MERGE_HEAD`

Answer (score 4):

When you `git add` to resolve a conflict, you erase the record of the conflict.  So to preserve this information without having to reconstruct it, preserve the index file:

```
cp .git/index .git/preserved-merge-index
```

and then

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/preserved-merge-index git ls-files --unmerged
```

will show you the conflicts, and

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/preserved-merge-index git diff-files --name-only
```

will show you everything in your work tree that's changed since it was recorded in the merge index.

From comments, you also might be *adding* files directly in the merge.  To catch those, after you've resolved all your merge conflicts you can

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/preserved-merge-index git diff-index --name-only `git write-tree`
```

Comment: This results in the same thing (in my little test case), and seems simpler. Mucking with .git/ files is a minus though.

Comment: Enh. "[full access to internals.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_description)"  `MERGE_HEAD` is a .git/ file too.  `git stash` isn't built to do what you're winkling it into doing. wrapping a layer of commands meant for other things around the mucking just gets in the way.

Comment: (to be more specific: `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is a published interface.  git's _meant_ to be used this way, and its internals are so simple and so robust that it rewards it. the command set isn't an abstraction, it's a toolkit. the repository structure is what the tools are there to help you work with, but there's no law or reason not to just do what needs doing)

Comment: Actually... I went back and tried this and could not reproduce the behaviour I wanted.  Here's my simple test and output: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/ZJNTQ5doduH6HiMWOVB5/ http://paste.pound-python.org/show/eV3ZwpEibL3mZsitqi8A/ I expect `conflict_file` and `commit_introduced_file` in the output.

Comment: You need to preserve the index file immediately after the merge, so work you've done since shows up as differences.  [Fixing that works](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/6GNWNug9vr67CUIYI9KY/) for the scenario in your question (conflicts and gratuitous edits), but it doesn't catch files gratuitously _added_ in the merge commit.  I've added something to catch that too.

Comment: How can I preserve the index immediately after the merge if I am running as a pre-commit?  I don't think I have access to that.

Comment: That's definitely too late, just save it before doing any conflict resolution.

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing me `git write-tree`, I ended up going with bukzor's approach and `git write-tree`: `git diff -m \`git write-tree\` HEAD MERGE_HEAD --name-only`  because I don't have the ability to save an index at the point I would need to.

Comment: How do you tell from the output of that whether changes to a file that had changes in both parents were conflicting?

Comment: See comments here: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/3ebf976afbadc74882e51c27475594d9f24444ce/pre_commit/git.py#L37,L51